# how to read value of parameter for any ddr4 module?

Tags: ddr

Kindly someone educate me how to interpret any data data sheet for memory.
I am refering to any data sheet for a ddr4 chip for example - https://www.3d-plus.com/data/doc/products/references/3dds_0758_2_ddr4_32gbx72_.pdf

Does nCK mean time for one clock cycle? for example, DDR4 that runs at 1600Mhz, nCK = 625ps.

what is the meaning when value of a parameter is given as Max(4nCK, 5ns)?
Does it mean - select  4nCK or 5ns, whichever is maximum?
In my example, where nCK  = 625ps, 4nCK = 2.5ns. Since 5ns is bigger than 2.5ns, I will select 5ns. 5ns is 5.0/0.625 = 8nCK.  so, is the value for this parameter 8nCK or 5ns?

For a given parameter, if the "unit" column has "nCK", then does it mean that value of this parameter be mentioned in cycles?

Am I the only one who does not know how to read datasheet for ddr as I could not find any useful information when I searched for  "how to read ddr4 data sheet"?

Comment: What data sheet? Please [edit] and provide a link.

Comment: My question was about any data sheet for ddr4. I added link to a datasheet to be used as an example. please can you open my question for answers.